# MYSQL5.1 Query that counts dates?

Tags: mysql, date, count

First query I need help with - I have a table named Stadium which holds info about different Stadiums. More than one game can be played at a certain Stadium per day. Stadium.Number refers to the number of the Stadium, Stadium.Date refers to the date of the game. I need to make a query which lists for each Stadium.Number, the date of which held the most games. If a certain stadium has two dates which have the same count of games, they should both be displayed.

For example with the following data below:

```
Stadium 1, 2012-03-19
Stadium 1, 2012-08-14
Stadium 1, 2012-08-14
Stadium 2, 2012-09-15
Stadium 2, 2012-09-15
Stadium 2, 2012-03-20
Stadium 2, 2012-03-20
Stadium 3, 2012-11-20
```

The query should return:

```
                    Stadium.Number   Busiest Date
                     Stadium 1,       2012-08-14
                     Stadium 2,       2012-09-15    (shows this and below 
                     Stadium 2,       2012-03-20     because they both have count 2)
                     Stadium 3,       2012-11-20
```

So far I have the following, but it doesn't work as I want it to:

```
SELECT Number, Date, count(Date)
FROM Stadium
group by Number,Date
order by count(Date) desc
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use:

```
 MAX(count(Date))
```

Comment: How would I use it? I've tried and not sure how exactly to do it? Thanks

Comment: Subqueries like above should do it.

Comment: Anyway of doing it without a subquery?

Answer (score 0):

This ugly beast ([sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/489dc/33)) is the first thing i could come up with.

```
select s.number, s.date, s.d
from (
    select number, date, count(date) as d
    from Stadium
    group by number, date
) s, (
    select number, date, max(d) m
    from (
        select number, date, count(date) d
        from Stadium
        group by number, date
    ) dates1
    group by number
) d2
where s.number = d2.number
and s.d = d2.m
;
```

Comment: I can't think of another way to do it right now. If your dates are stored as varchar they will display the same way you entered them. If you stored them as dates, like I did, you should take a look at the mysql docs on date and time functions.

Comment: What I meant is, is there anyway to edit this query so that instead of the date being in this format: August, 14 2012 00:00:00+0000, it's in this format: 2012-08-14?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, and the answer is in the mysql docs on date and time functions :) the date_format function is a good place to start